# Edit the email before sending with InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I am using InfoPath in SharePoint which sent automatic mail up on submit. I was wondering is there any way that we see and edit the email before sending it.

Comment: Rinu, are you sending email via InfoPath code-behind, rules or SharePoint Workflow?

Comment: SharePoint workflow

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can edit the email's content before sending. Create a column in your form library and put the email content inside it. In the SharePoint workflow, click inside the email body area and click `Add or Change Lookup`. Now select the `Field from source` the column that you created. Now before submitting the InfoPath form you can anytime edit/change the content inside this new column and the email body will carry the new text.

Even you can change the email recipients, Subject exactly the same way by creating custom column and referencing it through `Field from source`. For email recipients click on the book icon and choose `Workflow Lookup for a User.`

This is the only way I know you can edit the email before sending else email editing is only possible at design time in SharePoint Designer.

[image]

You can have an attachment control on your InfoPath form. Check this [ARTICLE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-file-attachment-control-8e8e102f-fad5-4440-bc28-d28944f85287).

Create a prompt message using Rules in InfoPath and remind the user to attach the file before submitting the form.

Comment: Hi Zakir, Thanks for the Reply, I have done the above but what i had issue is when the user clicks submit the infopath form should allow open up the outlook with all the content of the form. and the user should be able to attach a file before sending it. I know that sharepoint workflow sends the email automatically upon submit with all the information entered from the infopath . But what i need is to prompt before sending the email so that we can attach a file to it. I use sharepoint list form where the attachment is stored in the sharepoint.

Comment: is there any chance that we can store the attachment localy in the infopath form. I created a sharepoint list and click customize using infopath form. but i can only find one attachment field which is stored in the sharepoint and no attachment control is available in control are available either.

Comment: pls see my amended answer above.